# Python - Create new column in dataframe with year and month together

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below: DateTaken is datetime format

```
StudentId    DateTaken              Rating        Score
101           2015-09-16 14:04:23     3.6         85
101           2015-10-16 14:21:31     3.2         90
102           2015-10-21 15:13:21     2.0         75
```

I would like to create a column that would combine year and month only like:

```
StudentId    DateTaken              Rating       Score     YearMo
101           2015-09-16 14:04:23     3.6         85       2015-09
101           2015-10-16 14:21:31     3.2         90       2015-10
102           2015-10-21 15:13:21     2.0         75       2015-10
```

I have found a workaround using Group By that gets me what I need for my program BUT for me the challenge of solving this still exists. Is it possible?

Comment: I think your question is missing some tags. Is this pandas? What kind of dataframe are we talking about here?

Comment: Not sure if we are talking pandas, however couldn't you just convert to a string at take the first 7 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see comments ..... I didn't make my use of the field clear. I needed to retain ability to do date calculations

I was able to solve my problem with

```
df['DT2']= df['DateTaken'].values.astype('<M8[M]')
```

which truncated my data at gave me 2015-09-01..which served my purpose
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a slice of your value in a list comprehension like this :

```
df["YearMo"] = [ i[:7] for i in df["DateTaken"]]
```

Hope this work

Comment: Thanks. tried it and got following error
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable. I should have made it clear that I needed to do elapsed time calculations on the field. My erroe

Comment: Sorry, i assumed thoses where string.
Did you try 
    df["YearMo"] = [ str(i)[:7] for i in df["DateTaken"]]
?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a substring:

```
year_mo = date_taken[0:7]
```

this works only if your `DateTaken` field has consistent dates.

Another approach would be to load the timestamp and print it to the new format.

For this `python-dateutil` is your friend.

```
from dateutil import parser

# this gives you back a datetime object 
timestamp_taken = parser.parse(date_taken)

year_mo = timestamp_taken.strftime('%Y-%m')
```